# C# Serialization using Newtonsoft Json DefaultValue, How to do it?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, default-value

Using WebAPI2, I have a model class, and I am serializing it in a response.
I want to slim the data down.

I can do this by decorating the properties of model with JsonProperty attributes, and that is fine.

```
 [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
 public string AccountFee { get { return _accountFee; } set { _accountFee = value; } }
```

I have specified DefaultValueHandling to be Ignore, but I cannot get the setting of the default value correct.

The documentation says to use your preferred default in this property decoration...

```
[DefaultValue("DEFAULTACCOUNT")]
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
public string AccountFee { get { return _accountFee; } set { _accountFee = value; } }
```

But DefaultValue is not resolved.  I cannot figure out how to reference it correctly.

I have included using statements for Newtonsoft.Json and Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization, but still this is not recognised?  Am I missing a namespace, or using the attribute incorrectly?

Comment: `DefaultValue` attribute is only used by serializers to decide if the actual, current, value of the property should be serialized. The attribute does not in any way ensure the default value of the property is that value. If you want the property to start with that value as well, add an initializer to the property or the backing field.

Comment: You cant do that, you have to use `DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate` when you want to use `DefaultValue` attribute also

Comment: Can you tell us specifically what behavior you expected, instead of just "I tried this and it doesn't do what I expect it to do".

Comment: You may want to look at  new JsonSerializerSettings(){  NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore}

Comment: The `DefaultValueAttribute` is in the `System.ComponentModel` namespace, and not part of Json.NET. Is your situation simply "The compiler refuses to compile my code because it cannot find this attribute"?

Comment: The problem is, I set the default value to something (in this example, "DEFAULTACCOUNT", but could be anything), and then I would like to ignore this in the model.  My thinking was I would set the default value as above in the example, but DefaultValue does not resolve.  From @mww, I see what you are getting at, but can you give a code example for populate, I cannot get it working.  Apologies if original post was not clear.

Comment: @AlexKrupka; How would I use the JsonSerializerSettings?  I am using WebAPI2, and the serializer is 'under the hood', used when I pass data to an Ok<> handler.

Comment: What does "does not resolve" actually mean here?

Comment: When you have text the system does not resolve, it remains black, and will not compile.  When you correct it (through a fully qualified name or using reference) the compiler recognises it and colours it blue.  The compiler generates a CS0246 error, Type or Namespace not found, because it does not recognise [DefaultValue("")].  My guess is that I am using this in the wrong place, or not fully qualifying the namespace.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, I have tried adding a using reference for System.ComponentModel, and the DefaultValue now resolves.  I was assuming that this was a Json property, and assumption is the mother of all problem scenarios.  Would you like to post answer "DefaultValue requires using System.ComponentModel" type answer, and I can accept?